# Scala unit testing - stubbing a singleton

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mocking

I'm new to unit testing in Scala and I can't find a way to stub a function defined in a singleton object.

For example:

```
class Profile {
  def getLatest
    ...
    Feed.getLatestEntries
    ...
}

object Feed {
  def getLatestEntries: Future[List[FeedEntry]] { /* Access some API*/ }
}
```

I'm trying to unit test the `getLatest` function defined in the Profile class.
Since I don't want to actually access an external API through the web in my unit tests I'm trying to stub the `Feed` object and its `getLatestEntries` function to return some predefined value.

I've looked into the ScalaMock, EasyMock and Mockito frameworks but could not find a way to stub a method of a singleton object. ScalaMock states

How come all the mocking frameworks do not offer this functionality? How can I do this? stub `Feed.getLatestEntries` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My approach has been to create the logic of the singleton as a trait and then have the object extend the trait. This allows me provide the Singleton as a default or implicit argument, but provide a stubbed out implementation for testing

```
trait FeedLogic {
  def getLatestEntries: Future[List[FeedEntry]] { /* Access some API*/ }
}

object Feed extends FeedLogic

def somethingWantingFeed(...)(feed: FeeLogic = Feed) = { ??? }
```

Comment: Fair enough. But extracting object functions into traits only to make them stubable seems hacky to me - I don't think a testing technical issue should affect my code design. Is there any other justification to extract all object functions into traits?

Comment: I guess my counter argument would be that a singleton object that hides some kind of unconfigurable state or dependency, which makes it untestable in a functional way, is itself a design smell. Code should be testable without mocking framework's gymnastic, those capabilities being convenience for testing scenarios not enablers of them.

Comment: I see your point, I'm accepting your answer and giving +1 for composition. I've been reading a lot about the cake pattern, does this case somehow relates?

Comment: The Cake Pattern only relates in so far as that all Dependency Injection seeks to alleviate the pain of manually managing your dependency and just letting you call a method on a known instance, which in a much more limited way singleton also seek to provide. The goal at the end of the day is that you can just get at the resources you want from where you are without having to pass things around by hand. Cake's composition model is one way of arriving at this end.